# Modify XML element content(s) from 1 to 5 based on matching criteria(s)?

Tags: regex, xml, xslt, cmd, vbscript

This question requires replacement of values in an XML based on simple matching criteria (matches number 1).

**Criteria: For items matching TrackNumber 1 to 5):**

```
    FOR <ScannedTrack>
            WHERE <TrackNumber>1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5
IF <Codec>2048</Codec>

    OUTPUT/WRITE
          <Encoder>Ac3Passthrough</Encoder>
```

### Edit

I have simplifed this question and simplified the XML file so that answers can be correctly tested.

Comment: Well, what have you tried in terms of XSLT? And why does the sample posted XML not contain a single `<Codec>65536</Codec>` for instance if that is one of the values you say you need to check? In general, to use XSLT to transform some parts of an XML input you start with the identity transformation template and then add template matching those nodes you want to transform.

Comment: And what does the pseudo syntax `then  <Encoder>AacPassthru</Encoder>` mean exactly? Are there existing `Encoder` elements that need to be transformed to have the new value? Or do you need to create `Encoder` elements with that value as a child of some element? Where exactly? I guess you really need to break that up into smaller tasks where you present one XML sample, one condition that makes sense for the presented XML sample and then the required output XML for that sample and condition.

Comment: Anything shown above within a set of opened and closed brackets e.g. <Encoder>AacPassthru</Encoder> or <Bitrate>192000</Bitrate> is *actual* correct syntax. If you look at the example xml, the first <Encoder> string shows <Encoder>Ac3</Encoder>, if the criteria matches anything above the idea is for the existing string (anthing that exists already between the brackets) to be cleared entirely and replaced with the applicable string that matches any of the criteria e.g. "AacPassthru" as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transform XML to another XML where leaving parts unchanged while transforming some nodes based on conditions then you start the XSLT with the identity transformation template (which in XSLT 3 can be conveniently expressed simply by declaring `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>`) and then add templates matching the nodes you want to transform so your first three conditions might translate into

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="AudioTrack[ScannedTrack[Codec = (65536, 1111)]]/Encoder">
      <xsl:copy>AacPassthru</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="AudioTrack[ScannedTrack[Codec = 2222]]/Encoder">
      <xsl:copy>Mp3PassthruEncoderTool</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="AudioTrack[ScannedTrack[Codec = 3333]]/Encoder">
      <xsl:copy>Passthrough</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It is not possible to test that as you failed to provide any sample data matching your conditions.

Comment: The samples I have posted use integer literals in e.g. `Code = 2222` expressions, I don't see the difference for `Bitrate`. And I am not sure I understand your pseudo syntax, the XPath expression comparison operators are described in https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#doc-xpath31-GeneralComp

Comment: The "Bitrate" is read as an item of Input from the original file. Right now those items in <Bitrate> are stored in the xml as plain text/a string. I need to know whether the number is lower, higher or equal to the number in <Bitrate>, so I figure to work this out it needs to be an Integer.

Comment: Well, I have pointed to the list of comparison operators so it should be clear that you can write `Codec = 2048 and Bitrate <= 384000` in XPath (and in general in XSLT/XML you then have to escape the `<` as `&lt;` e.g. `Codec = 2048 and Bitrate &lt;= 384000`)